How can superconducting magnets have high inductance if $\mu_r= 0$ because of the Meissner effect?
I've gotten myself confused about superconductance and induction. My understanding is:
For a solenoid, the self-inductance is given by:
$$ L = \frac{\mu_0\mu_r N^2A}{l} $$
where $\mu_r$ is the relative permeability of the material.
But superconductors exhibit the Meissner effect, completely expelling magnetic fields, which would imply $\mu_r = 0$, right? Because expelling magnetic fields sounds like it's completely non-permeable.
But also, superconducting magnets are known to have very high inductance - this is why they need special techniques to ramp up current slowly due to $v = L\frac{di}{dt}$.
But this seems contradictory. If $\mu_r = 0$, wouldn't the formula predict $L = 0$? Clearly this isn't the case in practice. What's going on?

The parameter $\mu_r$ is the permeability of the material in the core of the solenoid. It is not the permeability of the conductors forming the windings surrounding the core. In a superconducting magnet the core is air or vacuum with $\mu_r\approx 1$.

Ah... yeah okay that makes sense. So they don't have a very high L at all, more like a normal L, but the entire benefit is only that you can safely run very high current through them without being limited by heating, up to the critical current of a few kA/mm². Is that the full story or am I missing any aspects?

Well, the main advantage of superconducting magnets is that you don't have to pay for electric power to use them.
